# Multiple auto-completion functions in one script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a command `pyseqtools.py` were I want to enable auto-completion for both a positional argument and a flag (`-a/--analysis`). I am able to auto complete either of them seperately with these lines of code in a separate auto-completion script:

```
stat_list="mageck bagel2"

function analysis()
{
case $3 in
    -a) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$stat_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
    --analysis) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$stat_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
esac
}

complete -F analysis pyseqtools.py
```

and

```
module()
{
    local opts
    opts="crispr rna-seq chip-seq cutrun"
    case $COMP_CWORD in
        1)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") )
            ;;

    esac
    return 0
}

complete -F module pyseqtools.py
```

When I put all the code in one auto-completion script, only the block of code that is the bottom of the file is working. How can I make both of them work in one script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by combining both functions into one:

```
stat_list="mageck bagel2"

function _complete()
{
case $3 in
    -a) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$stat_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
    --analysis) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$stat_list" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
esac

    local opts
    opts="crispr rna-seq chip-seq cutrun"
    case $COMP_CWORD in
        1)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") )
            ;;

    esac
    return 0

}

complete -F _complete pyseqtools.py
```